# Factoring out attributes for reuse in D3 transition

Tags: d3.js, svg, transition

In the minimal example below, an SVG element transitions to a different state and then reverts to the original. How can I factor out the original attributes so that they won't have to be repeated? `selection.each()` and `transition.each()` have been giving me unexpected confusing results.

```js
var circle = d3.select('svg').append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 50) // this part should be factored out
  .attr('cy', 130)
  .attr('r', 25)
  .attr('fill', 'blue');

circle.transition().duration(1000).delay(500)
  .attr('cx', 200)
  .attr('cy', 50)
  .attr('r', 50)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .transition().duration(1000).delay(500)
  .attr('cx', 50) // repeated
  .attr('cy', 130)
  .attr('r', 25)
  .attr('fill', 'blue');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg width='300' height='170'>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was `call()` instead of `each()`. I knew it was possible!

```js
function revert(selection) {
  selection
  .attr('cx', 50)
  .attr('cy', 130)
  .attr('r', 25)
  .attr('fill','blue');
}

var circle = d3.select('svg').append('circle')
  .call(revert);

circle.transition().duration(1000).delay(500)
  .attr('cx', 200)
  .attr('cy', 50)
  .attr('r', 50)
  .attr('fill','red')
  .transition().duration(1000).delay(500)
  .call(revert);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg width='300' height='170'>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to leverage the power of D3's [data binding](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data). You could define configuration objects containing both, the original values to be restored later on as well as the values to which the element should transition to. By binding this information to the DOM elements created by D3 you may access them in later calls. These configuration objects may look like this:

```
var circle = [{   // D3 binds data contained in arrays
  orig: {         // The original values
    "cx": 50,
    // ...
  },
  trans: {        // The values to transition to
    "cx": 200,
    // ...
  }
}];
```

Throwing in the [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) module you can directly use the above defined configuration objects by handing them to the [`selection.attrs()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi#selection_attrs) method:

The function’s return value must be an object with string values, which are then used to set attributes on the current element.

```js
// Array of configuration objects
var circle = [{
  orig: {
    "cx": 50,
    "cy": 130,
    "r":  25,
    "fill": "red"
  },
  trans: {
    "cx": 200,
    "cy": 50,
    "r":  50,
    "fill": "blue"
  }
}];

// Create new elements by binding data and using data joins
var circle = d3.select('svg').selectAll('circle')
  .data(circle)                               // Bind configuration objects to elements
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attrs(function(d) { return d.orig; });   // Use the original values

circle.transition().duration(1000).delay(500)
    .attrs(function(d) { return d.trans; })   // Transition to new values
  .transition().duration(1000).delay(500)
    .attrs(function(d) { return d.orig; });   // And transition back to original values
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>

<svg width='300' height='170'>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've actually avoided the repetition by storing the attributes in an object and calling `selection.attrs`, but it was unsatisfying to load a whole add-on to save several lines of code. I thought for sure that `.each()` was meant for something like this, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, the module is just 1733 bytes small and it is part of the original D3 universe. I included it to have the code look cleaner, more dense and more elegant. Of course, the same could be achieved by using calls to `.attr()` methods alone.

Comment: On the other hand, `.each()` will not be your friend for this.

Comment: But `.call()` is! See my answer. I appreciate your answer, though. Thanks again.